# Inline Images in Gatsby Wordpress source plugin

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm using this plugin https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/@draftbox-co/gatsby-wordpress-inline-images/ following all instructions, but does not work.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

gatsby-config.js:

```js
{
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
      options: {
        excludedRoutes: [
          '/wp/v2/users/**',
          '/wp/v2/settings*',
          '/wp/v2/themes*'
        ],
        baseUrl: 'domain',
        protocol: 'http',
        postTypes: ["post", "page"],
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `@draftbox-co/gatsby-wordpress-inline-images`,
            options: {
              baseUrl: `domain`,
              protocol: `http`
            }
          }
        ],
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        useACF: true,

        searchAndReplaceContentUrls: {
          sourceUrl: 'http://domain',
          replacementUrl: ''
        }

        
      }
    },
```

[image: My Gatsby Blog]

Comment: Are you defining a bearer? What do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Comment: Hi Ferran! In my Gatsby blog this is what happens: https://imgur.com/gallery/BILwnkJ

Comment: Does the plugin downloads properly the assets in the static folder?

Comment: This is the problem, assets are not sent to the static folder in Gatsby. Keeps the same wordpress path <img src = "/ wp-content / uploads / website-rebuilt-in-gatsbyjs.png">.I mean the images in the posts, everything works correctly except for that

Comment: I added you as a collaborator on my project on github. Can you help me?

Comment: Seems a very low-maintained plugin. Open an issue to the autor's repository because it seems clearly an issue. According to the description of the plugin, it should download the assets to the static folder.

Comment: I Will do that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could access the wordpress site both http and https. I just change protocol url (gatsby plugin config) to https and works

```js
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
      options: {
        excludedRoutes: [
          '/wp/v2/users/**',
          '/wp/v2/settings*',
          '/wp/v2/themes*'
        ],
        baseUrl: 'domain.net',
        protocol: 'https',
        postTypes: ["post", "page"],
        
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: '@draftbox-co/gatsby-wordpress-inline-images',
            options: {
              baseUrl: 'domain.net',
              protocol: 'https',
              withWebp: true,
            }
          }
        ],
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        useACF: true,

        searchAndReplaceContentUrls: {
          sourceUrl: 'https://domain',
          replacementUrl: ''
        }

        
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby is buggy sometimes when updating images and hrefs.

Try to clear cache.

```
gatsby clean
```

before

```
gatsby develop
```

Comment: Hi Rusty! Still the same root path: <img src="/wp-content/uploads/Capturar-300x184.png" alt="" width="300" height="184">

Comment: The src should point to gatsbys local image folder. Query the image url and import it to your module. The src should point to your local static folder abd not to the original source

Comment: what the plugin should do

Comment: Read this: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images/

Comment: I'm using gatsby-source-wordpressV3 and this plugin does not work with it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see inline images is because of your config:

```
 searchAndReplaceContentUrls: {
   sourceUrl: 'http://domain',
   replacementUrl: ''
}
```

If you remove it, you'll see inline images with the correct Wordpress src url. The downside is that your links (if you're using `gatsby-link`) won't be pre-fetched because they will have the Wordpress sourceUrl in the url.